# How do I convert continuous variables to factors easily?

Tags: r, dplyr, factors

Frequently, I need to convert a continuous variable (with only limited kinds of values) to a factor.

I usually use the code below, but recently I have error messages.

Can you make this code simpler?

```
DT2 <- DT1 %>%
  mutate_if(function(x) length(unique(x))<=3 & length(unique(x))>1,funs(as.factor))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
DT2 <- DT1 %>% mutate_at(c("col1", "col2"), as.factor)
```

where col is the name(s) of the column(s) you want to recast as factors

Comment: Sorry, I want to convert some of continuous variables selectively.

Comment: Can you designate the number of unique value of the continuous variable in mutate_at() ?

Comment: you cannot mix different classes in a single column. Either it is a factor or it is a number, character etc. You can add a new column that labels a row that satisfy you r criteria.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make that line "simpler" could specific the predicate function externally so it's easier to read. Something like this...

```
my_predicate <- function(x) {
  length(unique(x)) <= 3 & length(unique(x)) > 1
}

DT1 %>% 
  mutate_if(my_predicate, as.factor)
```

I believe this replaces the current column that satisfies this logic. If you want to create a new column from this, you can specify the name of the column by using a named list.

```
DT1 %>% 
  mutate_if(my_predicate, list(new_col = as.factor))
```